# Pytorch giving runtimeerror can't be cast to the desired output type Long

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, tensor, fairseq

The following code is giving runtimeerror "result type Float can't be cast to the desired output type Long".

I already tried to do the following:

**FROM:**
`torch.div(self.indices_buf, vocab_size, out=self.beams_buf)`

**TO:**
`torch.div(self.indices_buf, vocab_size, out=self.beams_buf).type_as(torch.LongTensor)`

Problematic code:

```
class BeamSearch(Search):

    def __init__(self, tgt_dict):
        super().__init__(tgt_dict)

    def step(self, step, lprobs, scores):
        super()._init_buffers(lprobs)
        bsz, beam_size, vocab_size = lprobs.size()

        if step == 0:
            # at the first step all hypotheses are equally likely, so use
            # only the first beam
            lprobs = lprobs[:, ::beam_size, :].contiguous()
        else:
            # make probs contain cumulative scores for each hypothesis
            lprobs.add_(scores[:, :, step - 1].unsqueeze(-1))

        torch.topk(
            lprobs.view(bsz, -1),
            k=min(
                # Take the best 2 x beam_size predictions. We'll choose the first
                # beam_size of these which don't predict eos to continue with.
                beam_size * 2,
                lprobs.view(bsz, -1).size(1) - 1,  # -1 so we never select pad
            ),
            out=(self.scores_buf, self.indices_buf),
        )
        torch.div(self.indices_buf, vocab_size, out=self.beams_buf).type_as(torch.LongTensor)
        self.indices_buf.fmod_(vocab_size)
        return self.scores_buf, self.indices_buf, self.beams_buf
```

This code is from fairseq.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this
self.beams_buf = self.indices_buf // vocab_size

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because Tensors can't handle math operations on different tensor types. Looks like `self.indices_buf` and `vocab_size` should both be Long tensors (an iterable of integer types).

Try to cast both to pytorch's `LongTensor` type, to ensure there's no type-mismatch:

```
self.indices_buf = Tensor(self.indices_buf).long()
vocab_size = Tensor(vocab_size).long()
```